# Can send email with Postfix, but cannot receive emails

Tags: linux, firewall

I am moving my email server from one server to another. I have tried everything, but can't get the email to receive any emails.

I think I have found the problem. It is is the firewall. I am using RedHat.

When I do the "list-all" command on the two servers, the output is identical, with one exception. The server on which I am moving my email server has, "forward: no" in the output. I believe this is the culprit.

My question is: How can I get rid of this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eno1
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client dns http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s smtp ssh
  ports: 3306/tcp 53/udp 53/tcp 25/tcp 443/tcp 80/tcp 587/tcp 465/tcp 110/tcp 143/tcp 22/tcp
  protocols: 
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Comment: Please share the complete output, a vague description does not really allow an answer.

Comment: I added the output above as coding

Comment: What is the error message from the bounce message you get when you try to send a mail to that server?

Comment: There is no error message. Just the opposite. It says, "Email sent successfully"

Comment: Do the postfix log files indicate anything about incoming mails?

Comment: No, there is nothing in the log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137595/discussion-between-charlie-and-gerald-schneider).